# Upgrading hardware and converting current host OS to a VM - any catches?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, activation, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I am currently using Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on my dev machine (where I am writing this post from). I also currently use VMWare Server and several VMs, all running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise x64 full installs (with the exception of AD being Server Core).

I want to upgrade my PC's mobo, CPU and RAM and before that, convert my host OS to a .VHD to run inside SCVMM 2008 R2 and do a fresh upgrade to Win Server, so lose 7 and the data (backing it up of course).

If I make the VHD of 7 - my current host OS, do a fresh install of Win Server as the host OS to get Hyper-V), and then load my VMWare VMs and this host OS (as a VHD) and the do the hardware upgrades, will I get any activation issues? I have a MAP subscription and I did have Windows Server in a VM complain it was not genuine so I had to re-activate it (I think because I upgraded my BIOS, this was the only change on the machine to invoke this in Windows Server). The activation is of course just calling that automated phone system to reactivate.

Even if there are any activation issues or the prompt to reactivate, would this risk any data loss? Or should I do the hardware changes first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activation issues will never cause data loss, worst cae scenario for activation problems is that you only get 2 hours of uptime and can't use Aero.  I would do that hardware upgrades before doing the install of server to save yourself one reactivation becasue if you do it in the order specified you will have to reactivate server again (unless of course you don't activate everything until you are all done- which is certainly an option)

Comment: When you say one reactivation, I assume just the host? Is there ever a scenario where the reactivation is not the case of a black bg and just ringing MS?

Comment: if a system in unactivated and considers itself not genuine you will have to reboot and put up with notifications.  So you will have to activate teh host  (2k8) and you will probably have to reactivate the windows 7 guest as well (since it's changinhg lots of hardware)